# simplifying equations

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I have a question that seems easy but I can't solve it.
I have an equation like:

```
eqgama = -8.33208*10^56 g1 + 8.18264*10^56 g1^2 == -1.42093*10^56
```

I use the following statements to find its discriminant:

```
poly = (eqgama[[1]] - eqgama[[2]]) // Simplify;
Discriminant[poly, g1];
```

The answer is:
2.29158*10^113

In another program mathematica itself simplifies eqgama to the following equation:

```
-1.97163*10^54 g1 + 1.93627*10^54 g1 ^2 == -3.36235*10^53
```

and so the discriminant becomes:
1.28315*10^108.

I have a loop and I want to plot discriminants versus a definite parameter, but in this loop sometimes Mathematica simplifies equations and sometimes not. So the plot fluctuates. What should I do?

Comment: Don't use subscripts... Rewrite your equations without them and update the code in your question

Comment: Your title could be better. The question isn't about simplification of equations as far as I can see. You claim to have problems with a loop and with plotting without specifying either. You should really try to improve and clarify your question or risk that it be closed.

Answer (score 11):

Discriminants are not scale free.

If you do

```
Discriminant[100 (x - a) (x - b), x] - Discriminant[(x - a) (x - b), x] // FullSimplify
```

you get

```
9999 (a - b)^2
```

So, what you can do is to transform your equations into monomials. Trying to respect your notation (which is not the better):

```
eqgama[1] = -8.33208*10^56 g1 + 8.18264*10^56 g1^2 == -1.42093*10^56;
eqgama[2] = -1.97163*10^54 g1 + 1.93627*10^54 g1^2 == -3.36235*10^53;

c2[x_] := Coefficient[x, g1, 2]
disc[x_] := Discriminant[#/c2[#], g1] &@(x[[1]] - x[[2]])
```

then:

```
disc /@ eqgama /@ {1,2}
(*
{0.342253, 1.03686}
*)
```

**Edit**

For plotting such things with a parameter, you could do something like:

```
eqgama[t_] := Cos@t  g1 + Tan@t g1^2 == Gamma@t; (* an example*)

Plot[disc@eqgama@t, {t, 0, 3}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Edit**

Also, please remember that Mathematica has many powerful tools to study parametric equations behavior.

Following with our toy example:

```
h[t_, g1_] := Cos@t g1 + Tan@t g1^2 - Gamma@t;
Grid[{Through[{Plot3D,DensityPlot,ContourPlot}[h[t,g], {t,0,Pi}, {g,0,5}]]}, Frame -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: thanks for your helpful answer.